# A Classic Conundrum

Tags: knowledge, anagram, literature

I had a quick idea for a puzzle that may or may not be too hard to solve, but *nothing* is too hard for Puzzling SE so let's give it a go.

---

One of my friends gave me a list of classic books to read last week. For fun I wrote down short descriptions of each of them and then crossed out the initials in the titles.

For example, Moby Dick became massive whale dies became assive whale ies.

The problem is, I've lost the original sheet with the authors and titles of the books. I've managed to recover most of them, but there are a couple long ones I'm having trouble on:

> joads  est (3)
>
> o illed over alleged rpe (4)
>
> mn ie fr cash (4)
>
> in the end she is (4)
>
> s boys ight (4)
>
> oaming the y (4)
>
> un oe acks everyone (5)
>
> oman not uilty after bad aher (6)
>
> niag ees a fish (6)

The letters in parentheses denote the amount of letters missing from the clue, ie the number of words in the title.

Bonus! Reaarange the books in the order you would find them in a library and pick letters out of the author's last names to get a bonus book:

> m 5 a66 c2 425 jo7 6 (5)

---

I'm not quite sure what else to tag this as...

Comment: You say you crossed the *Initials* out, and in many instances this seems to be the case. But it looks like there are many missing letters also on not-leading-position in words (i.e. "fr"). Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Do you remove all the instances the initials appeared in the description or only once?

Comment: @Cashbee I crossed out the initials of the book titles, not the descriptions.

Comment: @ImongMama Only once

Comment: @awesomepi ooooh now I see. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: There's 9 books listed, but only 8 numbers marked for extraction...?

Comment: @feelinferrety fixed

Answer (score 12):

**Partial Answer**

ads go est (3)

> **Go**ads go **w**est (although I think it may be Joads instead) 
>  and the book is **Grapes of Wrath** by *John Steinbeck*

o illed over alleged rpe (4)

> **T**o**m** **k**illed over alleged r**a**pe 
>  **To Kill a Mockingbird** by *Harper Lee*

mn ie fr cash (4)

> m**a**n **d**ie**s** f**o**r cash 
>  **Death of a Salesman** by *Arthur Miller*

in the end she is (4)

> in the end she is **laid** 
>  **As I Lay Dying** by *William Faulkner*

s boys ight (4)

> **Lo**s**t** boys **f**ight 
>  **Lord of the Flies** by *William Golding*

oaming the y (4)

> **R**oaming the **cit**y 
>  **Catcher in the Rye** by *J.D. Salinger*

oman not uilty after bad her (6)

> Although it doesn't quite fit, I think this must be 
>  **W**oman not **g**uilty after bad **weat**her 
>  **Their Eyes Were Watching God** by *Zora Neale Hurston* 
>  We need an extra "a" word in the title so perhaps the OP had the title in mind as something like **All Their Eyes Were Watching God**

Comment: Holy snap yeah I don't know why I though their name was Goads...

Comment: Wouldn’t “in the end she is” be “n the en she s”, if your title is correct?

Comment: @El-Guest actually what I'm suggesting is that all of the deleted letters were in "laid" (as in "laid to rest") an additional word in the sentence.

Answer (score 6):

Partial

niag ees a fish (6)

> **Sa**n**t**iag**o** **m**ee**t**s a fish = The Old Man and the Sea (Ernest Hemingway)

un oe acks everyone (5)

> U.N. O**w**e**n** a**tta**cks everyone = And Then There Were None (Agatha Christie)

The bonus:
m 5 a66 c2 425 jo7 6 (5)

> Chri**s**tie
>  Faulk**n**er
>  Goldi**n**g
>  H**e**mingway
>  Hur**s**ton
>  L**e**e
>  Mill**e**r
>  Saling**e**r
>  Stein**b**eck
>  m **s** a**nn** c**e see** jo**e** **b** (5)

Comment: and this is the moment where he realized that he accidentally arranged the authors' last names in the wrong order...